# Could not resolve project :reactnativemsal. (react-native-msal)

Tags: android, react-native

i am using react-native-msal module for implementing Azure AD B2C Login in react-native. I am getting build error in android **Could not resolve project :reactnativemsal.** Any suggestions might be helpful. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiaNE.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am just installing the module and run the project at that time i am getting build error. Code is not implemented.